# Optimizing Java File I/O for High-Volume Log Files

Tags: java, performance, optimization, logging, file-io

When I want to write Java code for writing text to a file, it usually looks something like this:

```
File logFile = new File("/home/someUser/app.log");
FileWriter writer;

try {
    writer = new FileWriter(logFile, true);

    writer.write("Some text.");

    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am now writing a `Logger` that will be used extensively by an in-house reporting tool. For reasons outside the context of this question, I can't use one of the traditional logging frameworks (SLF4J, Log4j, Logback, JUL, JCL, etc.). So I have to make something homegrown.

This logging system will be simple, non-configurable, but has to be capable of handling high-volume (possibly hundreds of log operations per second, or more).

So I ask: how can I optimize my normal file I/O template above, to handle high-throughput logging? What kid of "*hidden gems of Java File I/O*" can I capitalize on here? Pretty much anything goes, except, like I said, use of other logging frameworks. Basic `Logger` API needs to be something like:

```
public class Logger {
    private File logFile;

    public Logger(File logFile) {
        super();

        setFile(logFile);
    }

    public void log(String message) {
        ???
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: If my `Logger` used a `ByteOutputStream` instead of a `FileWriter`, then how can I properly synchronize my `log(String) : void` method?

```
public class Logger {
    private File logFile;

    // Constructor, getters/setters, etc.

    public void synchronized log(String message) {
        FileOutputStream foutStream = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
        ByteOutputStream boutStream = new BytesOutputStream(foutStream);

        boutStream.write(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using a BufferedOutputStream instead of a FileWriter.  You will probably want to synchronise writes to the BufferedOutputStream.  Maybe set the buffer size to somewhere around 8MB to reduce throughput hits from disk seeking to something fairly minimal.

Comment: Thanks @tmyklebu (+1) - I'm very interested in your statement "*Maybe set the buffer size to somewhere around 8MB to reduce throughput hits from disk seeking to something fairly minimal.*" Can you elaborate a little? I'd say of all the input this question has gotten so far, your comment here is the most helpful. If you were to make a formal answer I'd probably give you the green check ;-). Thanks again!

Comment: Eyeballing the numbers here:  Disk seeks take about 8ms.  Your southbridge can probably push about 1GB/s to your disk array.  Your disk array is probably slower than that and it might have better things to do; in particular, if you're talking about a single disk, you get about 100MB/s.  8ms * 1GB/s tells you that the time taken to do a disk seek could have been spent writing 8MB of stuff, or 800k for a single disk.  This eyeballing all goes out the window if you're using flash or an array on your LAN, since the latency and throughput numbers are different.

Comment: Thanks againa @tmyklebu (I wish I could upvote you more!) - Please take a look at my code update - is that how I should be synchronizing the log method (using `ByteOutputStream`), or is there a better way? Also, **`ByteOutputStream` already seems to be thread-safe (every method)** - so do I even need to try and add my own synchronization on top of it? Why/why not? Thanks again!

Comment: The big win is to move from unbuffered to buffered I/O.  Doing the char -> byte conversion in advance is rather more minor.  I'm unfamiliar with your ByteOutputStream.

Comment: Thanks @tmyklebu (+1 again - you *really* should answer this question, I'd give you another +1 and a favorite)! Also, what about opening/closing the streams? Should I be doing this on every write, or, like with DB connections, is there a way to have a "persistent stream" so I can capitalize on perf gains from not having to open/close stream with each log method call?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve maximum throughput for the logging operation you should decouple the logging of messages from writing them to the file system by using a queue and a separate log-writing thread.

Comment: Then you have questions about how big of a buffer you should use and stuff like that.  And you have to balance the perceived throughput gain here against throughput losses everywhere else in your system thanks to the extra thread contending for CPU time, doing all sorts of unnecessary interprocessor communication, and I/O'ing at possibly-bad times.  (As tempting as it may be, you can't ignore the unbounded memory consumption issue. since it's never good when programs run out of memory and die.)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a logging system isn't just to achieve maximum throughput. It is required as an audit trail. Business decisions must be made as to how much data loss, *if any,* is tolerable in case of a crash. You need to investigate that first, before committing yourself to any specific technical solution.

Comment: Bang-on.  Ultimately, though, you need to satisfy both the functional requirements and the performance requirements of your system.  Sometimes that means you have to compromise on one or the other or piss off your users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm speaking only about throughput here and not about engineering or reliability concerns, since the question asked only about performance.

You will want to buffer writes to disk.  Writing lots of little tiny pieces with unboffered I/O incurs a whole bunch of overhead:

- The cost of a native method call; the JVM has to do a good amount of bookkeeping, including knowing which threads are running native methods and which aren't, in order to work.  This is on the order of tens or hundreds of nanoseconds on modern platforms.
- Copying the data from the Java heap to native memory through a magic JNI call.  There's a memory copy taking time proportional to the length of your data, but there's also a bunch of JVM bookkeeping.  Ballpark the bookkeeping overhead around a few hundred nanoseconds.
- The cost of an OS call to `write()` or similar.  Ballpark the overhead around 2 microseconds.  (There are other costs, too; your caches and TLB have probably been flushed upon return.)  `write()` also needs to copy the data from user space to kernel space.

The OS may internally buffer your writes.  It may not.  This depends on the OS and the characteristics of the underlying filesystem.  You can typically force it not to buffer your writes.  You can typically also flush the OS's buffer.  Doing so will incur the cost of a disk seek and a write.  Ballpark the disk seek around 8ms and the write between 100MB/s and 1GB/s.  Throw the disk seek overhead out the window if you're using a RAM disk or flash storage or something like that --- latencies there are typically much lower.

The really big cost you want to avoid if possible is the disk seek cost.  8 milliseconds is a hell of a long time to wait when writing a 100-odd-byte log message.  You will want some kind of buffering between the user and the backing storage, whether it's provided by the OS or hidden by the logging interface.

The overhead of a system call from the JVM is also significant, though it's about 1000 times less than the cost of a disk seek.  You're spending two or three microseconds to tell the kernel to buffer a write of 100-odd bytes.  Almost all of those two or three microseconds are spent handling various bookkeeping tasks that have nothing at all to do with writing a log message to a file.  This is why you want the buffering to happen in userspace, and preferably in Java code instead of native code.  (However, engineering concerns may render this impossible.)

Java already comes with drop-in buffering solutions --- `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedOutputStream`.  It turns out that these are internally synchronised.  You'll want to use `BufferedOutputStream` so that the String-to-bytes conversion happens outside of the lock rather than inside.

You could do one better than the `Buffered` classes if you kept a queue of `String`s that you flush once it reaches a certain size.  This saves a memory copy, but I rather doubt this is worth doing.

On buffer sizes, I suggested something around 4MB or 8MB.  Buffer sizes in this range cover up the latency of a disk seek fairly well on most typical modern hardware.  Your southbridge can push about 1GB/s and a typical disk can push about 100MB/s.  Maxing out your southbridge, then, an 8MB write will take about 8 milliseconds --- roughly as long as a disk seek.  With a single "typical modern disk", 90% of the time spent doing an 8MB random write is spent doing the write.

Again, you can't do buffering inside Java if log messages need to be reliably written to the backing store.  You need to trust the kernel in that case, and you pay a speed hit for doing so.